# Vertical LinearLayout with weights & marginTop -ve

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to create a screen something like this but without the white space at bottom **(please click on the image if you can't see the white space)**.

The red portion should occupy 40% of the height. Remaining (60% + (-24dp marginTop) ) by the black layout.

Also, I have 2 different requirements:

1. This exact screen **(already answered by ADM)**
2. This entire screen should be scrollable(inside NestedScrollView) **(solution needed)**

[image]

Following is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="40"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-24dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I know this can be resolved by giving a fixed height, but I DONT want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Solution can be multiple maybe it will be easy with `FrameLayout` and `ConstraitLayout`. Below is solution with combination and `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3.8" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="6.2"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer works fine. Can you also tell me how to make the same situation work if the entire page is a NestedScrollView?

Comment: You said in question the black part is going to be scroll view . So just put scrollview in place of linearlayout .

Comment: if entire page is nested scroll view I think it will act like same as linearlayout cause you have divided weight .

Comment: If this answer helped you pls accept and upvote . Thx